# Turn off error reporting XAMPP 1.8.3-1

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp

I am trying to turn off error reporting when using XAMPP 1.8.3-1, however modifying XAMPP's PHP.ini file does absolutely nothing at all. Here's my PHP.ini file, as you can see, I've turned off display_errors and set notices to off, but still they display. Any help would be appreciated!

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.

; PHP attempts to find and load this configuration from a number of locations.
; The following is a summary of its search order:
; 1. SAPI module specific location.
; 2. The PHPRC environment variable. (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 3. A number of predefined registry keys on Windows (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 4. Current working directory (except CLI)
; 5. The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP
; (otherwise in Windows)
; 6. The directory from the --with-config-file-path compile time option, or the
; Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt)
; See the PHP docs for more specific information.
; http://php.net/configuration.file

; The syntax of the file is extremely simple.  Whitespace and Lines
; beginning with a semicolon are silently ignored (as you probably guessed).
; Section headers (e.g. [Foo]) are also silently ignored, even though
; they might mean something in the future. 

; Directives following the section heading [PATH=/www/mysite] only
; apply to PHP files in the /www/mysite directory.  Directives
; following the section heading [HOST=www.example.com] only apply to
; PHP files served from www.example.com.  Directives set in these
; special sections cannot be overridden by user-defined INI files or
; at runtime. Currently, [PATH=] and [HOST=] sections only work under
; CGI/FastCGI.
; http://php.net/ini.sections

; Directives are specified using the following syntax:
; directive = value
; Directive names are *case sensitive* - foo=bar is different from FOO=bar.
; Directives are variables used to configure PHP or PHP extensions.
; There is no name validation.  If PHP can't find an expected
; directive because it is not set or is mistyped, a default value will be used.

; The value can be a string, a number, a PHP constant (e.g. E_ALL or M_PI), one
; of the INI constants (On, Off, True, False, Yes, No and None) or an expression
; (e.g. E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE), a quoted string ("bar"), or a reference to a
; previously set variable or directive (e.g. ${foo})

; Expressions in the INI file are limited to bitwise operators and parentheses:
; |  bitwise OR
; ^  bitwise XOR
; &  bitwise AND
; ~  bitwise NOT
; !  boolean NOT

; Boolean flags can be turned on using the values 1, On, True or Yes.
; They can be turned off using the values 0, Off, False or No.

; An empty string can be denoted by simply not writing anything after the equal
; sign, or by using the None keyword:

;  foo =         ; sets foo to an empty string
;  foo = None    ; sets foo to an empty string
;  foo = "None"  ; sets foo to the string 'None'

; If you use constants in your value, and these constants belong to a
; dynamically loaded extension (either a PHP extension or a Zend extension),
; you may only use these constants *after* the line that loads the extension.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About this file ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP comes packaged with two INI files. One that is recommended to be used
; in production environments and one that is recommended to be used in
; development environments.

; php.ini-production contains settings which hold security, performance and
; best practices at its core. But please be aware, these settings may break
; compatibility with older or less security conscience applications. We
; recommending using the production ini in production and testing environments.

; php.ini-development is very similar to its production variant, except it's
; much more verbose when it comes to errors. We recommending using the
; development version only in development environments as errors shown to
; application users can inadvertently leak otherwise secure information.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Quick Reference ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; The following are all the settings which are different in either the production
; or development versions of the INIs with respect to PHP's default behavior.
; Please see the actual settings later in the document for more details as to why
; we recommend these changes in PHP's behavior.

; allow_call_time_pass_reference
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
    Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
    Development Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

; html_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: Off

; log_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; magic_quotes_gpc
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)

; output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096

; register_argc_argv
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; register_long_arrays
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; request_order
;   Default Value: None
;   Development Value: "GP"
;   Production Value: "GP"

; session.bug_compat_42
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.bug_compat_warn
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.gc_divisor
;   Default Value: 100
;   Development Value: 1000
;   Production Value: 1000

; session.hash_bits_per_character
;   Default Value: 4
;   Development Value: 5
;   Production Value: 5

; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; track_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; url_rewriter.tags
;   Default Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset="
;   Development Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
;   Production Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

; variables_order
;   Default Value: "EGPCS"
;   Development Value: "GPCS"
;   Production Value: "GPCS"
```

Comment: All of these lines are just commented out and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Sorry, Amal - my mistake. I've uncommented the lines and still the errors display.

Comment: can you check in your phpinfo(); ?

Comment: @SajunaFernando, phpinfo() says they're on, but XAMPP's php.ini has them set to off.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple PHP file called `phpinfo.php`:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Run it, and check the entry where it says `Loaded configuration file` - this is the configuration in charge. If you modify this file your settings should be reflected *after* you've restarted Apache - when on Linux run `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restartapache`, on Windows use the control panel.

Comment: Thanks - phpinfo() is loading the correct php.ini file, with the 'display_errors' flag set to off in development mode, however phpinfo() says errors are turned on. I've tried multiple times to restart apache, but errors stay on.

Comment: Maybe you're overriding the INI values with some .htaccess directives (`php_flag`) ?

Comment: Doesn't look like it - I have no .htaccess files present.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well I seem to have gotten around this problem with some tweaking of @ErnestV's comment - I've created a .htaccess file (there wasn't one present before) and set a php_flag to display_errors off, which has solved my issues.

If there's a better way around this, I'd love to know it but, for now, that seems to have worked perfectly.